# access returned object in another class

Tags: c#, class

I'm trying to read id3 tags from a directory and I found some code online i've been trying to understand.

I understand most of it except the method `GetTag()`, it creates a new instance and returns an object but i can't access it from my main program.

```
public class Mp3Reader
{
    private string _fileName;
    private Stream _stream;
    private byte[] data;
    private const int SIZE = 128;

    public Mp3Reader(string fileName)
    {
        _fileName = fileName;
        _stream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    }

    public Mp3Tag GetTag()
    {
        Mp3Tag tag = new Mp3Tag();
        data = new byte[SIZE];
        _stream.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End);
        _stream.Read(data, 0, SIZE);
        //_stream.Close();
        byte b1 = data[0];
        byte b2 = data[1];
        byte b3 = data[2];

        if ((Convert.ToChar(b1) != 'T') || (Convert.ToChar(b2) != 'A') || (Convert.ToChar(b3) != 'G'))
        {
            throw new Exception("This File is NOT a MP3 file with ID3 v1");

        }

        for (int i = 3; i < 33; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] != 0)
                tag.Title += Convert.ToChar(data[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 33; i < 63; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] != 0)
                tag.Artist += Convert.ToChar(data[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 63; i < 93; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] != 0)
                tag.Album += Convert.ToChar(data[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 93; i < 97; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] != 0)
                tag.Year += Convert.ToChar(data[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 97; i < 127; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] != 0)
                tag.Comment += Convert.ToChar(data[i]);
        }
        tag.Genere = data[127].ToString();
        
        return tag;
    }
}
```

main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string folder = @"D:\\508-507-2209 (2017)";
    
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
    foreach(var val in files)
    {
        Mp3Reader tag2 = new Mp3Reader(val);
        tag2.GetTag();
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

mp3tag.cs

```
public class Mp3Tag
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Genere { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

If I manually `Console.WriteLine(tag.xxx)` right above my return it'll output to the terminal fine, what I don't understand is what to do with the "tag" variable that it created. why can't i access `tag.Title` in my main program?

```
tag.Genere = data[127].ToString();

Console.WriteLine("Title: " + tag.Title);
Console.WriteLine("Artist: " + tag.Artist);
Console.WriteLine("Album: " + tag.Album); ;
Console.WriteLine("Year: " + tag.Year);
Console.WriteLine("Comments: " + tag.Comment);
Console.WriteLine("Genere" + tag.Genere);
    
return tag;
```

Comment: "it creates a new instance and returns an object " exactly, now you only need to grab this object and save its reference in a variable: `var savedObject = tag2.GetTag();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't this be

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string folder = @"D:\\508-507-2209 (2017)";
        
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
        foreach(var val in files)
        {
            Mp3Reader tag2 = new Mp3Reader(val);
            Mp3Tag mp3tag = tag2.GetTag();  // <- this here
            Console.WriteLine("");
            
        }
```

Comment: 12 hours and it was that simple thanks!